# What does this notation mean in TLS documentation?

Tags: ssl

For example, looking at RFC 7301, which defines ALPN:

```
   enum {
       application_layer_protocol_negotiation(16), (65535)
   } ExtensionType;
```

The `(16)` is the enum value to be used, but how should I read the `(65535)` part?

From the same document:

```
   opaque ProtocolName<1..2^8-1>;

   struct {
       ProtocolName protocol_name_list<2..2^16-1>
   } ProtocolNameList;
```

...how should I read the `<1..2^8-1>` and `<2..2^16-1>` parts?

Comment: I am no specialist, here is my educated guess: (16) denotes a 16 bits data. (65535) is the default (or maximum ?) value. <1..2^8-1> is a value from 1 to 255 inclusive. <2..2^16-1> is a value from 2 to 65535 inclusive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation is described in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446.

---

For "enumerateds" (enums), see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-3.5, which says that the value in brackets is the value of that enum member, and that the enum occupies as many octets as required by the highest documented value.

Thus, if you want to leave some room, you need an un-named enum member with a sufficiently high value.

> One may optionally specify a value without its associated tag to force the width definition without defining a superfluous element.

> In the following example, Taste will consume two bytes in the data stream but can only assume the values 1, 2, or 4.

```
  enum { sweet(1), sour(2), bitter(4), (32000) } Taste;
```

---

For vectors, see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-3.4. This says:

> Variable-length vectors are defined by specifying a subrange of legal lengths, inclusively, using the notation <floor..ceiling>.  When these are encoded, the actual length precedes the vector's contents in the byte stream.  The length will be in the form of a number consuming as many bytes as required to hold the vector's specified maximum (ceiling) length.

So the notation `<1..2^8-1>` means that `ProtocolName` must be at least one octet, and up to 255 octets in length.

Similarly `<2..2^16-1>` means that `protocol_name_list` must have at least 2 octets (not entries), and can have up to 65535 octets (not entries).

In this particular case, the minimum of 2 octets is because it must contain at least one entry, which is itself at least 2 octets long (u8 length prefix, at least one octet in the value).

To make the octets/entries distinction clear, later in that section, it says:

```
   uint16 longer<0..800>;
            /* zero to 400 16-bit unsigned integers */
```